# Show that $[3,2]=\emptyset$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

Show that $[3,2]=\emptyset$

I don't know the meaning of the question. $\emptyset$ is the empty set and a closed interval $[a, b]$ is valid if $a<b$. What the question actually means and how to show this?

Comment: What is the exact, verbatim definition of $[a,b]$ used in the textbook that contains this problem?

Comment: The LaTeX command for printing the empty set is `\emptyset` not `\phi`. Compare: $\emptyset – \phi$. (I have now corrected your text source.)

Answer (score 7):

$$[3,2] = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}| 3 \leq x \leq 2 \}= \emptyset$$

No number is greater or equal to $3$ and less than or equal to $2$ simultaneously.

Comment: +1 Short enough to be a comment, good enough to be an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have assumed is correct. What the question says here is to prove that a set whose lower bound is 3 and upper bound is 2 is actually a null set.

Which actually is quite true. Since the lower bound of a set cannot be greater than the upper bound, so the given set must be a null set.

Comment: Nitpick: "null set" usually means "set of measure $0$", not "empty set".

Comment: [*a* lower (or upper) bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_and_lower_bounds) of a set is well defined, but *the* lower bound is not. Secondly a lower bound of a set *can* be greater than an upper bound. If this happens then it can be concluded that the set is empty.